# Pascal: How can I select items from ListBox1 to display results in listBox 2?

Tags: delphi, listbox, pascal, lazarus

I am new to Pascal Programming. I have been following online tutorials as close as possible.For my Program, I wish to be able to select an Item from List  Box 1 (A country), and have the results(Cities) displayed in list box 2. I know it there is probably a simple solution. Any help is appreciated.

```
       procedure TForm1.ListBox1Enter(Sender: TObject);
           begin
               ListBox1.Items.Add('America');
               ListBox1.Items.Add('United Kingdom');
               ListBox1.Items.Add('France');
           end;
```

The results just for example could be
America-New York,Washington,Phoenix
United Kingdom- York,London,Manchester
Spain - Madrid,Barcelona,Valencia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A listbox has an `ItemIndex` property which tells you the index into its `Items[]` array of the item which is selected (or  -1 if none is);

So, you can use the `ItemIndex` to get the text value of an item in the listbox (`AString := Listbox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex]`) and use that to call `Items.Add` on the second LB.

Obviously you can access any value in the listbox's `Items[]` array in code, regardless of whether it's shown as selected in the gui.

Note that the Items array of a ListBox, like many other arrays in Delphi, is zero-based.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a quick example for you, just create a new form, drop 2 listboxes on it and declare the OnCreate Handler for the Form and the OnClick Handler for the first ListBox.

Note that the use of the constant array of record is just a quick placeholder.

```
interface

uses
  Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    ListBox2: TListBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

type
  //just a quick Record to contain a country and 3 cities
  //this should be an dynamic array later.. or a class
  TCountryCitiesRecord = record
    Country: string;
    Cities: array[0..2] of string;
  end;

const
  //declare our 3 countries and their cities as constant
  //this might be loaded from a file or whatever later
  FCountriesCities : array[0..2] of TCountryCitiesRecord  =
  ((Country: 'USA'; Cities: ('New York','Washington','Phoenix')),
  (Country: 'United Kingdom'; Cities: ('York','London','Manchester')),
  (Country: 'Spain'; Cities: ('Madrid','Barcelona','Valencia')));

//onCreate of Form
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  //Initialize the first ListBox with the countries
  for I := Low(FCountriesCities) to High(FCountriesCities) do
    ListBox1.Items.Add(FCountriesCities[I].Country)
end;

//onclick of listbox1
procedure TForm1.ListBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    I: Integer;
begin
  //clear the second listbox
  ListBox2.Items.Clear;
  //if an item is selected
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1 then
    //add the cities, that belong to the currently selected country
    //to the second listbox
    for I := Low(FCountriesCities[ListBox1.ItemIndex].Cities) to High(FCountriesCities[ListBox1.ItemIndex].Cities) do
      ListBox2.Items.Add(FCountriesCities[ListBox1.ItemIndex].Cities[I])
end;

end.
```